# Why do html/css texts appear so "pixelated" compared to texts from photoshop or gimp?

Tags: fonts, text

Here is an example to explain what I mean:

Text created in Gimp:

[image]

Text created in html/CSS code:

[image]

```
font: 60px "anchor-web-1","anchor-web-2", 'Impact', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
```

---

Why do html/css texts appear so "pixelated" compared to texts from photoshop or gimp?

And is there a way to have better result and still use only html/css/javascript/other code?

Comment: What browser/OS is your second example from?

Comment: @e100 Chrome/WindowsXP

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to an outdated technology.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example uses Gimp's anti-aliased [font rasterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_rasterization). In short, the glyphs are given a smoother appearance by using grey pixels where the outline would bisect a pixel.

It also uses hinting to keep the verticals on exact pixel boundaries and therefore crisp.

Text rendered by operating systems and browsers uses anti-aliasing to different degrees; your second example, Chrome on Windows XP isn't using any at all.

If you try a few different browsers yourself you may see different results. What your visitors will see is also dependent on the browsers and OS they are using and not really under your control; they'll see other websites' text rendered similarly.

Comment: How would you advise to improve the rendering for the most visitors of my website(s)?

Comment: You can't improve the rendering. The best you can do is try different fonts until you find one that renders well in the os/browsers most of your visitors are using

Comment: @tucson you can use "safe" type fonts, http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/16-gorgeous-web-safe-fonts-to-use-with-css and just get the best of what you can or if you really need it to look great, you will need to create an image.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the OS than the browser. Some browsers might try and anti-alias, but you can have windows try and emulate it. I don't like how it does it though, it always looks out of focus.

Comment: The point is, as yisela says, you have no control over what OS and font-rendering the user is using.  Your only option is to pick a font that looks as good as possible on as many different OSes as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, is the **ClearType** anti-aliasing (font smoothing) feature off? I hear it's not turned on by default in XP, only in later versions. There is a Microsoft help page on how to activate ClearType:
http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use;

```
    .sumTextElement{
           filter:blur(0.57px);
    } /* Anywhere from 0.44px to 0.59px seems to work */
         May loose some crispness but its a trade-off
         Have to play around to get the optimal setting.

         Can also add a filter contrast to negate any crispness loss

         Larger text you can get away with a larger blur, smaller text 
         needs a finer touch. Hope this helps.
```